# How do I use the "Investor" perk?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I just purchased the investor (Speech) perk, and I'm wondering how to use it.

Specifically, I'm trying to invest in one of my fences, and I see no additional options.

How do I use my perk, and is it possible to invest in a fence?

Comment: Have you tried talking to a store owner?

Comment: @DavidYell Not yet, I just stopped playing, I'm in the middle of some thieves guild quests so the only "store" owners I've come across are fences and the merchants in the thieves guild, but neither the fences or those merchants act any differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't invest in any of the stores/fences in the Ragged Flagon. However, if you were to speak to one of the shop owners in the cities (Angela's Aromatics in Solitude, or Warmaiden's in Whiterun for example) you'll get a dialogue option that says "I'd like to make an investment in your store." I believe the main reason you can't invest in the stores in the Ragged Flagon is due to the fact that:

> Upon completing the Thieves' Guild missions, the main fence in the bar will have around 4000 gold to barter with, making investing unnecessary.

Comment: I don't know about "unnecessary"; at high levels you get many times more than that from a single dungeon crawl with the lockpicking loot perks.

Comment: It probably has to do with the next perk in that line, which turns any shop you've invested at into a fence.

Comment: I've invested in several stores where it has been an option but only ever had the riverwind trader (first one I did) ever show up with more money. Can you only invest in 'one' ?

Answer (score 2):

You can invest in any that have the dialogue, annd ups their amount of money by (your) 500g. There is a bug that turns your investment in lucan valerias at riverwood trader from 500 into 10k.